# "Uncaught DOMException: CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage: Passed-in image is "broken"" error

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing a tutorial from  Chris Courses on youtube with vertical platformer game using html and javascript, and I'm having some trouble. The error goes
`Uncaught DOMException: CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage: Passed-in image is "broken"`
The lines it's referencing (aka, whenever I'm trying to use the picture):

```
class Sprite {
    constructor({position, imageSrc}){
        this.position = position;
        this.image = new Image();
        this.image.src = imageSrc;
    }
    
    draw(){
        if (!this.image){
            return;
        }
        c.drawImage(this.image, this.position.x, this.position.y); \\referencing this line
    }
    
    update(){
        this.draw(); \\and this
    }
}
```

and

```
function animate() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate); \\this one
    c.fillStyle ='green';
    c.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    background.update(); \\and this
    
    player.update();
    player.velocity.x = 0;
    if (keys.a.pressed && lastKey === 'a') {
        player.velocity.x = -1;
    }
    else if (keys.d.pressed && lastKey === 'd') {
        player.velocity.x = 1;
    }
 }
```

this is the code I'm using to 'input' the pic

```
const background = new Sprite({
    position: {
        x:0,
        y:0
    },
    imageSrc: './sprites/bg.png',
})
```

I've tried using images made by myself and downloaded, different sizes, changed names and everything, rechecked my code and I still can't solve it.

Here's the whole code

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const c = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = 1024;
canvas.height = 576;
c.fillStyle = 'green';
c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
const gravity = 0.3;

class Sprite {
    constructor({position, imageSrc}){
        this.position = position;
        this.image = new Image();
        this.image.src = imageSrc;
    }
    
    draw(){
        if (!this.image){
            return;
        }
        c.drawImage(this.image, this.position.x, this.position.y);
    }
    
    update(){
        this.draw();
    }
}
class Player {
    constructor(position){
        this.position = position;
        this.velocity = {
            x:0,
            y:1
        };
        this.height = 50;
    }
    
    draw(){
        c.fillStyle = 'black';
        c.fillRect(this.position.x, this.position.y, 50, this.height);
    }
    
    update(){
        this.draw();
        this.position.y += this.velocity.y;
        this.position.x += this.velocity.x;
        if (this.position.y + this.height + this.velocity.y < canvas.height) {
            this.velocity.y += gravity;
        }
        else{
            this.velocity.y = 0;
        }
    }
}

const player = new Player({
        x:10,
        y:10,
});

let lastKey;

const keys = {
  a: {
    pressed: false
  },
  d: {
    pressed: false
  },
  w: {
    pressed: false
  }
}

const background = new Sprite({
    position: {
        x:0,
        y:0
    },
    imageSrc: './sprites/bg.png',
})

function animate() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    c.fillStyle ='green';
    c.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    background.update();
    
    player.update();
    player.velocity.x = 0;
    if (keys.a.pressed && lastKey === 'a') {
        player.velocity.x = -1;
    }
    else if (keys.d.pressed && lastKey === 'd') {
        player.velocity.x = 1;
    }
 }

animate()

window.addEventListener('keydown',(event) =>{
    switch (event.key) {
        case 'd':
            keys.d.pressed = true;
            lastKey = 'd';
        break;
        case 'a':
            keys.a.pressed = true;
            lastKey = 'a';
        break;
        case 'w':
            player.velocity.y = -5;
        break;
    }
    console.log(event.key);
})

window.addEventListener('keyup',(event) =>{
    switch (event.key) {
        case 'd':
            keys.d.pressed = false;
        break;
        case 'a':
            keys.a.pressed = false;
        break;
    }
    console.log(event.key);
})
```

Comment: May be it has to do with image itself. I've tried your code and not getting an error. https://jsfiddle.net/derloopkat/f0er29za/ Is the path correct?

Comment: @derloopkat the pictures themselves were not the problem, but I figure there was some error in the way I linked them. This time I used picture uploaded to a site (still made by me) and it worked. So there is something wrong with this line `imageSrc: './sprites/bg.png',`, even though that is a good path and the picture is there.

Comment: It is a relative path. The dot represents the current directory. So from the location of the page there should be a "sprites" directory with the image inside. Have you double checked that?

Comment: If the image is in your hard drive and you're testing it locally also try `imageSrc: 'file:///./sprites/bg.png'`

Comment: I am testing it locally. Double checked, it's there. Tried `imageSrc: 'file:///./sprites/bg.png'`, still image is broken. I'm honestly running out of ideas

Comment: I just tested your original code with a local image and worked fine. Does this happen with other images?